# How can I test if a spirit (tequila) has oxidised?

Tags: home-experiment

Is there a way to test if tequila has oxidised and if so the level of oxidisation?
It would be best if this could be done without a control sample, but the most important thing is if I can do this with 'household' equipment  - although I do have access to a hydrometer.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one. Can I assume you want to know the percentage of ethanol oxidised to acetic acid? I would assume, that this might be a bit complicated with household items. Tequila itself is a wild mixture of compounds, accurate determination of all compounds is a challenge itself.

Comment: I guess, checking the taste isn't good enough for you? ;)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン "percentage of ethanol oxidised to acetic acid" sounds like the kind of thing we're looking for.

Comment: @Mithoron it's the taste that's made us want to conduct these tests - it was a brand new bottle but seems a little different to the expected taste

Comment: To my knowledge tequila and other high percent stuff doesn't have problem with turning alcohol into acid, as acetic fermentation can't proceed  in solutions with high ethanol content